# How do you compare strings in SQL by aplhabetical order?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Querying the following two tables:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MTCorrelations](`

```
[CorrelationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[StockA] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[StockB] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[Correlation] [float] NOT NULL,
[LengthStr] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Industries](

```
[IndustryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Symbol] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[Sector] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Industry] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

)

with this query:

Select StockA, StockB, Correlation, LengthStr From MTCorrelations
WHERE
StockA IN 
(Select Symbol From
Industries WHERE Industry = 'Money Center Banks')
AND 
StockB IN
(Select Symbol From 
Industries WHERE Industry = 'Money Center Banks')
ORDER BY Correlation DESC

The result produces duplicates because the table has duplicates where StockA vs StockB correlation is listed in one row and the same correlation is listed in another row that has StockB is in the StockA column and vica versa.

Since each correlation is listed twice, I figured to add a where clause to limit the results to those in which stockA is alphabetically before stockB. I tried a < between stockA and stockB and it didn't work. Does SQL have an comparison operator for strings?

Comment: Ah, the famous computer software problem: "It didn't work". Care to give more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this, it is more efficient and does not produce permutatation of A/B:

```
SELECT StockA, StockB, Correlation, LengthStr From MTCorrelations
WHERE StockA < StockB AND -- This is to remove the permutations
  EXISTS                  -- Fast check for StockA being within constraints
  (SELECT * 
   FROM Industries 
   WHERE Industry = 'Money Center Banks' AND 
         Symbol = StockA) AND
  EXISTS                  -- Fast check for StockB being within constraints
  (SELECT * 
   FROM Industries 
   WHERE Industry = 'Money Center Banks' AND 
         Symbol = StockB)      
ORDER BY Correlation DESC
```

Comment: That's basically what he is trying to do. `IN` and `EXISTS` will get [exactly the same plan](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/)